# Lightning issue - Constant light that doesn't enable the use of other lights

Tags: light

I'm following Blender Guru's tutorials, and I'm doing the last part that consists of lightning the chair. When I try to put the spotlight, I can't really see the difference because it seems to have a global light that I don't know how to shut down. In the final render, you can see that only the screws have a shadow, the chair remains with constant light in it. Could someone help me? Thanks! ^^ [image]

Comment: in what shader mode are you? Material or Rendered?

Comment: Any chance you forgot a Shader node and plugged your Image Texture directly into the Material Output?

Comment: @moonboots  In rendered.

Comment: @Christopher Bennett It is not. It is plugged in base color, in 'Principled BSDF'

Comment: Strange, it appears to be "un-shaded". And you say this is happening in the render as well as the viewport?

Comment: @Christopher Bennett It worked!!! ^^ You were right! The Image texture was connected with the Material Output indeed! I connected the surface in Material Output in the BSDF from Principled BSDF and it worked! Thanks a lot!!! ^^

Answer (score 1):

That happens when you are not using a shader and plug a texture directly to the surface of the material.

[image]

.

Plugging a texture directly to the material output, the texture becomes  emission source.

[image]

Shaders define what happens to light rays on the surface of an object. Without a shader... well... there is no shading..

Use a shader and plug the texture as color.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @susu for your explanation! Super well detailed, it will certainly help others! :)